# Creating and deploying a standard build of OS X 10.6 company-wide

Tags: macos

My company is growing quickly and we are purchasing a lot of iMacs. Up until now each one has been configured individually but I'd like to be able to define default settings (network settings, Safari settings, dock settings etc) which I can apply automatically on a machine.

I'm assuming this can be done, but where do I start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done using [Apple Remote Desktop 3](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/) and a Task Server(s). It's available in the Mac AppStore for $79.

Another useful and powerful software is [DeployStudio](http://www.deploystudio.com/Home.html), which automates disk image installation over a network.

Answer (score 3):

See this question: [OS X 10.6 : Automating new system provisioning with scripts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6149/os-x-10-6-automating-new-system-provisioning-with-scripts). From my answer:

> The IT department at my company
>   maintains a disk image [on an external
>   Firewire drive] with all of the
>   settings in place they need to
>   administer the Macs when they are
>   received-including software in place
>   registered with site licenses. They
>   open the Macs and simply replace
>   what's on the hard drive with the disk
>   image.

Comment: We used to image that way. If you get more than a couple Macs at a time, this is very time-consuming (and therefore expensive). mspasov's suggestion is more reasonable for a large deployment, although the upfront cost can be more substantial, if you don't have an available machine to run ARD on. Your method is better suited for an organization that only deploys a few machines a year.